# How do c/c++ preprocessors work when encountering unknown directives?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Do c/c++ preprocessors process all lines that begin with #?
Does is errors out when encountering unknown macros or will it just ignore them?

for an example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#hello
int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

what happens in this situation?will it produce an error or will it work (ignoring #hello line)?

Comment: There are no guarantees.  It's a tricky situation.  If I accidentally type `"#incude` or `#deifne`, I definitely want the compiler to warn me.  If I've got code that's supposed to be "portable" but that I also use with a nonstandard processor that accepts `#funkydirective`, I might not want an ordinary compiler to warn me.  In practice, all "funky directives" should be collected under `#pragma`, so I would say that compilers generally *should* warn about unrecognized directives.

Comment: But surely you could try it to see what it does in *practice*?

Comment: It is using the "shall not" language in the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p3). Which is "*In this International Standard, ''shall'' is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, ''shall not'' is to be interpreted as a prohibition.*".

Comment: The Standard says that unrecognized directives are an error, IIRC, but since it's a quality-of-implementation issue what kinds of errors or warnings a compiler emits, or what kinds of extensions it accepts, I expect there's a fair amount of latitude here.

Comment: MSVC stops right there: `fatal error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'hello'`. It isn't a macro, that is with `#define`.

Comment: Unless it's a [`#pragma`](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pragma) or something defined by that implementation it should fail, that is the behavior defined in the standard

Comment: It showed an output saying that "error: invalid preprocessing directive #hello", so is it safe to think that preprocessor tries to process every line that starts with #. This is actually a question in a university paper. I'm not sure what they mean by processing. Can it be considered as processing if the preprocessor error out?

Comment: Error is a result of processing.

Comment: Any sane compiler should show an error such as `error: invalid preprocessing directive #hello`

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not trying beforehand. So I think the statement that "C preprocessor processes all the lines that start with a # in c file." is correct.

Comment: @Nethrenial. yes the preprocessor will process a line that starts with `#hello` and then it will fail when it doesn't understand `hello`.

Comment: Regardless of what the standard says, a compiler would be useless if it simply ignores a directive with a typo such as `#defin FLAG` and then makes a gross error with `#ifdef FLAG`.

Comment: @Nethrenial. "C preprocessor processes all the lines that start with a # in c file." sound not  right. since it need to substitute `#define`s it need to process **every** token

Comment: @appleapple uhh, so it is a trick question. Uhh, why can't teachers give clear questions? It seems like the answer depends on how the lecturer defines the word "processing" regards to this topic

Comment: @Nethrenial. Yes, unfortunately, there's a class of instructor which loves to pose questions involving overly significant interpretations or idiosyncratic definitions of certain words, and it can be impossible to answer such questions "correctly" without being inside the mind of the instructor.

Comment: @Nethrenial. well at least it doesn't say it don't touch other line so it may be good. BUT then again. I believe `#if` make it skip a region of code (it still need to *process* every line for checking `#elif` `#endif` ... though)

Comment: or, if you mean it may stop when encounter unknown token (as the question), I think I should mention `#error` here.

Comment: @Nethrenial. The initial `#` token of the preprocessing directive does not necessarily occur at the start of a line. It could be preceded by white-space characters and/or C-style comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, you accepted an incorrect answer. See the comments on the answers for an explanation.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language grammar specifies all pre-processor directives that exist in the language. If you use any other name for the directive, then that is a "conditionally-supported-directive". If the conditionally supported directive isn't supported, then the the language implementation is required to issue a diagnostic message and is free to refuse to proceed.

Comment: The compiler is also free to continue to compile the program, with an implementation-specific meaning. +1.

Comment: This answer is wrong; lines with `#` followed by tokens that do not form a preprocessing directive are explicitly a part of the C grammar, as shown in C 2018 6.10 1 (which shows the grammar production rules for this) and 3 (which says the *non-directive* grammar token excludes the defined preprocessor directives). Further, such a non-directive preprocessing directive (unfortunate wording but used by the standard) does not violate the constraint in C 2018 6.10 5 and therefore does not require a diagnostic message. The standard deliberately leaves the grammar here open for extensions.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the comment by @EricPostpischil (and the other, correct answer), `#` _non-directive_ is called out by the grammar, where _non-directive_ consists of pp-tokens.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I couldn't delete the answer, so I edited it instead.

Comment: A program with a *conditionally-supported-directive* is not ill-formed, regardless of whether the C++ implementation supports it. An “ill-formed program” is not one that is “well-formed” (C 2017 draft N4659 [defns.ill.formed]). A “well-formed program” is one “constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the one-definition rule” ([defns.well.formed]). Conditionally supported directives are in the grammar and so obey the syntax rules. The one-definition rule is not involved. No semantic rules for conditionally supported directives are stated;…

Comment: … a diagnostic is required only because [intro.compliance] 2.2 says “If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in this document as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message,” which treats non-support of a conditionally supported construct as separate from violations of diagnosable rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've edited correspondingly.

Answer (score 5):

### C

Syntactically, `#hello` is a "*non-directive*" preprocessing directive.

C17/C18 section 6.10 paragraph 9 (newly added in C17/C18) says:

> The execution of a non-directive preprocessing directive results in undefined behavior.

"Undefined behavior" does not necessarily mean that the compiler will fail to translate the code or issue a diagnostic. (EDIT: As pointed out by Eric Postpischil in the comments, execution of a non-directive preprocessing directive does not violate a constraint so a diagnostic is not required.) It could behave in a documented manner, for example if the directive is part of an extension to the C language.

### C++

Syntactically, `#hello` is a "*conditionally-supported-directive*" preprocessing directive.

C++20 section 15.1 paragraph 2 says:

> A *conditionally-supported-directive* is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics.

"Conditionally-supported" means that an implementation is not required to support it. Implementations need to document all conditionally-supported constructs that they do not support. (In the case of *conditionally-supported-directives*, I guess that would amount to documenting that none of them are supported, or documenting the semantics of those that are supported.)

Comment: This answer is correct, and, further, a non-directive preprocessing directive does not violate the constraint listed for preprocessing directives in C 2018 5, so no diagnostic message is required.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, noted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An ***unrecognized preprocessing directive error*** will rise, and your code won't compile